# PHP and MySql, join three tables and reading

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 database tables, `products`, `categories`, and `assignment`

All three tables have a unique id.

The third table `assignment`, associates product IDs with the category IDs. An example:

```
products:
---------------------
| name        | id  |
---------------------
| white shirt | 234 |
| black pants | 0u2 |

categories:
---------------------
| name       | id   |
---------------------
| shirts     | x23  |
| pants      | 28x  |

assignment:
------------------------
| catId | itemId | id  |
------------------------
| x23   | 234    | 892 |
| 28x   | 0u2    | 561 |
```

I want to create a list. An example:

```
<items>
<cats>shirts</cats>
<item>white shirt</item>
<cats>pants</cats>
<item>black pants</item>
</items>
```

It is important that the first category name and then products are listed in the category.

Sql:

```
select assignment.itemId, assignment.catId from assignment 
    left join categories 
        on categories.id = assignment.catId 
where categories.active = '1'
```

**My SQL query works fine**. The problem is in a while loop to provide list correctly together.

PHP while loop:

```
            if ($res != false && $res->count() > 0) {
                $i = 0;
                $html = '<items>';
                while (!$res->EOF) {
                    $categories = $res->fields[1];
                    $html .= '<cats>'.$categories->title.'</cats>';
                    $products = $res->fields[0];
                    $html .= '<item>'.$products->title.'</item>';
                    $i++;
                 }
                $html .= '</items>';
              }
```

In a while loop I can read products fields[0] and categories fields[1], but I can't make a list like I want.

my result is as follows:

shirts
pants

white shirt
black pants

do you have any solutions for me?

thank you!

Comment: Which SQL queries have you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins - (A comprehensive guide to JOINS)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/29211643/custom-join-query-to-get-record-from-3-table

Comment: as has already been written. I can read and combine all tables. My problem is a loop in PHP While.

Comment: Can you paste your while loop code here

Comment: can you show your php code?  I see none posted in the question but you say your troubles are in that loop.  Without the code we cannot tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have updated my code. 

I had to change something that code to the public. But the loop works and I have all the values. But put together as I would like, unfortunately, does not work.

Comment: do you have any solutions for me?

Comment: You have nested data loops of: _`<cat>`_ and _`<items>`_ within the the _`<cat>`_. That is fine. Have you tried to structure your code to have the same structure? i.e. nested _`while`_ loops to process the corresponding _data_ structures? You should have a `while loop` for _`items`_ inside a _`while loop`_ for _`cat`_. It will work fine.

Comment: I tried for hours, unfortunately, does not work. categories are counted separately.

What I want is to read category name and list all the products of this category and if this is done next category name and their products as a Sitemap.

Comment: Yes, two nested while loop I have tried. That's what I tried but get no structure. Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: I would attempt this in the easiest way to code possible. I am _never_ concerned about efficiency in the first instance,  I need something that works. So: 1) Get at list of _`cats`_. and print them out.Step two: modify the programs to:  Inside that loop, get the products for the current _`cat`_. Print them out.  Ok, is not efficient. I suspect it will work.

Comment: Oh, performance is important. It could hundreds of categories and 10,000 - 30,000 be products available. :-(

Do you have any code examples?